# Axios не удается получить JSON

Tags: json, google-maps-api, axios

Использую Google Maps Api, а конкретно DistanceMatrix и Geocode.
Чтоб получить нужный JSON, использую Axios. 
По get запросу с браузера/постмана все приходит, а Axios не может получить json от DistanceMatrix.
Вот тот самый JSON:

axios.get('[https://https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Krasnodar&destinations=Moscow&mode=driving&key=мойключ](https://https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Krasnodar&destinations=Moscow&mode=driving&key=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87)');

```
{
    "destination_addresses": [
      "Москва, Россия"
    ],
    "origin_addresses": [
      "Краснодар, Краснодарский край, Россия"
    ],
    "rows": [
        {
    "elements": [
        {
          "distance": {
            "text": "1 345 км",
            "value": 1344860
          },
          "duration": {
            "text": "14 ч. 41 мин.",
            "value": 52875
          },
          "status": "OK"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status": "OK"
}
```

---

Ошибка:

```
Failed to load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?
origins=Krasnodar&destinations=Moscow&key=мойключ: No 'Access-Control-Allow-
Origin' header is present on 
the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8090' is therefore not 
allowed access.
spread.js:25 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
at e.exports (spread.js:25)
at XMLHttpRequest.l.onerror (spread.js:25)
```

---

JSON от Geocode получается отлично.